# Como fechar uma session em PHP

Tags: php

Estou tendo problema ao tentar destruir as sessões, tentei o código abaixo, existe alguma forma além dessa?

```
<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

O que ocorre é que as váriaveis de sessão não são destruídas, dessa forma conseguindo resgatar os valores contidos nela.

Comment: O que você entende por "finalizar sessões"?

Comment: Estou tentando fazer que o usuário realize o "logoff"

Comment: Já leu a [documentação da função `session_destroy()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-destroy.php)?

Comment: Infelizmente não sei o que houve de errado. Quando eu faço o Logoff ele realiza o redirecionamento para a página "Index.php" mas quando eu forço o acesso para uma outra página como "Home.php", Ele entra na página normalmente como se eu estivesse logado.

<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
?>
Esse é o meu código para "logoff"

Comment: A pergunta ficou mais clara?

Comment: Não, qual foi o "problema" que está tendo?

Comment: A pergunta já foi respondida, estou tentando deixa-lá mais clara com os padrões do site. vou edita-lá novamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente fazer umas alterações:

Na tua pagina "App Help Desk" retire o trecho:

```
session_destroy();

header('Location: index.php');
```

Crie uma uma página com o nome:
**logoff.php**

e cole o código abaixo em logoff.php

```
session_destroy();

header('Location: index.php');
```

Answer (score 4):

Para encerrar sessão você deve usar isso em seu código PHP.

```
session_destroy();
```

Caso queira criar uma sessão pode fazer dessa forma em seu codigo PHP:

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['usuario'] = "User1";
```

Caso queira obter algum valor da sessão em seu codigo PHP:

```
echo $_SESSION['usuario'];
```

Comment: Quando eu faço o Logoff ele realiza o redirecionamento para a página "Index.php" mas quando eu forço o acesso para uma outra página como "Home.php", Ele entra na página normalmente como se eu estivesse logado.

<?php
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
?>
Esse é o meu código para "logoff"

Comment: Tente fazer algumas alterações: vou colar como resposta.

Answer (score 3):

Faça a seguinte alteração em **Home.php** na primeira linha de código:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    /* Aqui você está verificando se a sessão está setada,
     * quando ele fizer logoff, seu session_destroy fará com que ele não entre na página
     */
    if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
?>
```

Então, modifique o login também. Adicione este código se o login foi feito com sucesso:

```
...
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
...
```